# ScrollView with animation xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to know how to do the following horizontal scrollview with animation : so the button closer to screen center so is bigger.

And I also would like to know how to position the button like in the picture.

[image: horizontal scrollview with buttons]

Thanks :)

Comment: Show us your XAML/Code so that we might help/suggest you something. If you asks like hey how to do that then there's 100000s of different ways to implement and we can't point you out to any direction. We won't try anything unless you show something that we can think and help you on

Comment: @NirmalSubedi Thank you for reply. I dont have any idea how to do it. I search all over the internet and didnt find even something similar to this.

Comment: Was eager to know how you achieved it. just to know different way.

Answer (score 1):

**Query 1:**

If I understand you correctly, you want all the visible views inside the scrollview to change their scale according to their position.

This can be achieved by using a custom view and binding the scrollview's `Width` and `ScrollX` to it to change the view's Scale.

[My solution working gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN8fC.gif)

Created CustomView derived from `ContentView`. Added three BindableProperties each for `ScrollX`, `Width` of ScrollView and `Position` of the view in the scrollview.

For all three BindableProperty's `PropertyChanged` bound a single method `OnScaleFactorsChange` and calculated the scale of the view accordingly.

**Bindable properties in CustomView**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets ScrolledPosition
    /// </summary>
    public double ScrolledPosition
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrolledPositionProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ScrolledPositionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="ScrolledPosition"/> bindable property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScrolledPositionProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ScrolledPosition", typeof(double), typeof(CustomView), 0d, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnScaleFactorsChange);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Position
    /// </summary>
    public double Position
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PositionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="Position"/> bindable property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty PositionProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Position", typeof(double), typeof(CustomView), 0d, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnScaleFactorsChange);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets ScrollViewWidth
    /// </summary>
    public double ScrollViewWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollViewWidthProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ScrollViewWidthProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="ScrollViewWidth"/> bindable property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScrollViewWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ScrollViewWidth", typeof(double), typeof(CustomView), 0d, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnScaleFactorsChange);
```

**OnScaleFactorsChange method**

```
 private static void OnScaleFactorsChange(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newValue)
        {
            (bindable as CustomView).ChangeScale();
        }

        private void ChangeScale()
        {
            var itemWd = this.Width;

            var itemPresent = this.ScrollViewWidth / this.Width;
            double ratio = 0;

            var scrolledItems = this.ScrolledPosition / this.Width;

            double totalRatio = ((this.Position - 0.5 - scrolledItems) / (itemPresent / 2));

            if (totalRatio > 0 && totalRatio < 2)
            {
                ratio = totalRatio > 1 ? 2 - totalRatio : totalRatio;
            }

            // Minimum scale 0.75 , maximum scale 1(0.75 + 0.25)
            this.Scale = 0.75 + 0.25 * ratio;
        }

Also call the scale changing method in SizeChanged event

        public CustomView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeChanged += CustomView_SizeChanged;
        }

        private void CustomScrollView_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeScale();
        }
```

Finally use it inside `ScrollView`'s `BindableLayout`'s `ItemTemplate` and bind the properties.

**Sample page XAML**

The Position is given in the Model of the Item.

```
<ScrollView
    Grid.Row="1"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    x:Name="scrollview">
    <StackLayout
        Padding="0"
        Spacing="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CustomItems}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomView
                WidthRequest="50"
                Padding="20"
                BackgroundColor="#aaff0000"
                Position="{Binding Position}"
                ScrolledPosition="{Binding Source={x:Reference scrollview}, Path=ScrollX}"
                ScrollViewWidth="{Binding Source={x:Reference scrollview}, Path=Width}">
                    <Grid Padding="20" BackgroundColor="#aaf000aa">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Position}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </local:CustomView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This might be a long way around but this is the only way I was able to achieve this.

Please do ask if any clarification is required.

**Query 2**

The button position can be achieved by many ways. I have listed a few below.

**1:Using Grid column**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button
            Grid.Column="1"
            BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
            Text="Hi there"/>
</Grid>
```

**2:Using Vertical and Horizontal option**

```
    <Grid>
            <Button
                BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Hi there"/>
        </Grid>
```

**3:Using AbsoluteLayout**

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
                <Button
                    BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.2,0.2"
                    Text="Hi there">
                </Button>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Tried to achieve it in the simple binding but later found that a custom view could to be to achieve it easier hence posted this.

**Hope this could help you.**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CardsView` to do that.

`CardsView`: https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView

Download the sample code from the GitHub.
In `CoverFlowSampleXamlView`, the sample use the custom control `PanCardView`. The part of `CoverFlowView` could do the horizontal scrollview.
In the sample code, it use the image, you could change it to the `ImageButton`.

**CoverFlowSampleXamlView.xaml**

Change:

```
<ffimage:CachedImage Source="{Binding Source}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```

To:

```
<ImageButton Source="{Binding Source}"></ImageButton>
```

**CardsSampleViewModel.cs**

Change the source. I add five images in the Resources/drawable folder.

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<object>
                 {
            new { Source = "a.jpg" },
            new { Source = "b.jpg" },
            new { Source = "dog.jpg" },
            new { Source = "c.jpg" },
            new { Source = "d.jpg" }
        };
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hey, I tried this ,it works on UWP local machine and Android simulator but not in my device.

Comment: What is the version of your device? What deos it look like on your device?

Comment: Android 9 Galaxy note 9, there is big space in the place of the control ,in the size of the images , only the "TO LAST" button is displayed on screen.

Comment: The url of images in the sample code does not work well. Do you change the source like what i said in my reply?